# Monotonically increasing bijection $f$ that continuously maps unit interval into itself such that for $a, b \in (0, 1)$, $f(a) = b$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given $a, b \in (0, 1)$,  I seek a simple (ie. perhaps a rational), monotonically increasing, bijective, non-piecewise, continuous function $f\colon [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ that such that $f(a) = b$.

Basically, $f$ can be thought of as continuously mapping $[0, a] \mapsto [0, b]$ and $[a, 1] \mapsto [b, 1]$. So a piecewise example of such an $f$ could be one where the intervals are just scaled linearly into one another.

However, I'm struggling with coming up with something non-piecewise. Can anyone assist please?

Comment: The above has many errors.

Comment: The title doesn't match the body of the post. If the version in the body is meant to be the correct one, hint: polynomials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple function is $$f(x) = x^{\log_a b}$$

and here is a rational one $$f(x)=\frac{(1-a)bx}{a(1-b)+(b-a)x}$$

Comment: That rational function is precisely the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to accept the use of absolute value you can take:

$$f(x) = \frac{(b-a)(a-\left|x-a\right|)+(a+b-2ab)x}{2a(1-a)}$$

which is just the linear interpolation from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ to $(1,1)$.